# Interactive multiway tree/graph applet with mouse listeners

Tags: java, animation, data-structures, applet, multiway-tree

I have a graph in which the nodes have 0 or more successors and 0 or more predecessors. 
I want to make a visualization (preferably through JAVA) such that:

1. There should be a search box. If I enter the id of the node the node should appear on the screen.
2. If I left click a node, it's children should appear below the node(in tree representation).
3. If I right click the node then it's parent should appear above the node.
4. If I double click any node then it should have same effect as searching the node(as in point 1)

I want to know what approach should I follow (any package etc.)? Is there some similar implementation whose code I may reuse?

Comment: *" I want to make a visualization (preferably an applet) such that:"*  You have our permission.  *Go for it!*  You've described a problem, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question?  But as far as 'applet' goes.. Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  Also *"Thanks.
Avinash."*  Don't include sigs. in questions.  They are noise.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the Question.